# All desktop icons open the same program/file

Tags: windows-7, icons

My problem is that every icon on my desktop opens the exact same program.
for a while, no matter which icon i clicked on, it only opened an old word document again and again.
When i tried to delete the word document, an old Excel spreadsheet kept opening in it's place.
Can anyone please help me resolve this?

Comment: Does it only apply to desktop, or other shortcuts? (eg. in the Start menu). Was this file created by you? Does it contain macros? Does right-click on an icon work and are you able to see properties of each shortcut?

Answer (score -2):

see if this addresses your problem:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-can-i-restore-the-default-file-associations-in/c096cd7a-91cd-4460-af4d-f38d7ca54860

Comment: Please, don't provide answers that are just links, try to improve the it by writing steps that can be followed.